# How to have checkboxes checked based on values are matching from two different arrays?

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

I am trying to check specific boxes if an array contains values of array2.

**HTML**:

```
<section class="example-section">
  <mat-label>someLabel</mat-label>
  <mat-checkbox
    class="example-margin"
    *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index"
    #checkBox
    [value]="option"
    name="option "
    (change)="getCheckbox(checkBox)">
    {{ option }}
  </mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

**TS**:

Here I am comparing two arrays to see if array1 values matches array2 values. If the array1 matches set the isCheck flag is true. else false. But seems like this logic is correct to some extent.

```
@Component()
class SomeComponent {
  isChecked: boolean;
  user = {
    option: ['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']
  };
  optionValues: string[] = [
    '8045',
    '4444',
    '8069',
    '8155',
    '2222',
    '8220',
    '8299',
    '3333',
    '8344',
    '8396',
    '8397',
    '8495',
    '1111',
  ];

  test() {
    this.user.option.forEach(user => {
      this.optionValues.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element + ' @@@@@ ' + user);
        if (element == user) {
          console.log('Found match @@@@' + element);
          isChecked = true;
        } else {
          console.log('No Match @@@@' + element);
          isChecked = false;
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**Attempt**

**HTML**:

```
<section class="example-section">
  <mat-label>someLabel</mat-label>
  <mat-checkbox
    class="example-margin"
    *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index"
    #checkBox
    [value]="option"
    name="option "
    [checked]="isChecked"
    (change)="getCheckbox(checkBox)">
    {{ option }}
  </mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

But this will set my values as false, because it seems like it only goes to component to pull "isChecked" value after the loop is completed.

**Example output**:

```
8045 @@@@@ 8069
No Match @@@@8045
1111@@@@@ 1111
**Found match @@@@1111**
8155 @@@@@ 8069
No Match @@@@8155
8220 @@@@@ 8069
No Match @@@@8220
8299 @@@@@ 8069
No Match @@@@8299
8344 @@@@@ 8069
No Match @@@@8344
8396 @@@@@ 8069
No Match @@@@8396
8397 @@@@@ 8069
```

All my checkboxes will be unchecked. Based on my current logic, because the final value for "isChecked" is false. What steps or changes I need to make in order to get the HTML to check the value of isChecked during the time when it's looping with ngFor?

Comment: It'd be better if you could provide a stackblitz. Currently it's hard to know how the arrays structure and also what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just want checkboxes checked if the checkbox value matches the array this.user.option.

Comment: [**Check this**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhyv9h).

Comment: @developer033 This is very very helpful! Thank you. I just have one question, how can I convert "this.user.option" array into selectedOptions: Record<string, boolean> = { 1111: true}; if that makes any sense.

Comment: Hence, the array(user.option) is coming dynamically, How can I set those values into selectedOptions array as {string,boolean}?

Comment: Could you fork the stackblitz and put your case there so I can take a look?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhyv9h-j2wxw3

I added a simple array called userValue. How to add those values into "selectedOptions"

Comment: @developer033 resolved the issue, can you set your stackblitz as answer? I will accept.

Comment: Glad to heat that. I've just posted it as answer with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform the options that come in `Array` into an `Object`, like this:

```
// Pre selected options that come from somewhere 
const preSelectedOptions: readonly string[] = ['8045','8069','8155','8220','8299'];

// Here you'll have { 8045: true, 8069: true } and so on...
readonly selectedOptions = preSelectedOptions.reduce<Record<string, boolean>>(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => ({
    ...previousValue,
    [currentValue]: true,
  }),
  {},
);
```

... why? Doing this way, it'll be better to bind in HTML using `[(ngModel)]`, like this:

```
<section class="example-section">
  <mat-label>someLabel</mat-label>
  <mat-checkbox
    class="example-margin"
    name="option"
    *ngFor="let option of optionValues"
    [value]="option"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions[option]">
    {{ option }}
  </mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhyv9h)